# Moving a file on Linux in C

Tags: c, linux

- Platform: Debian Wheezy 3.2.0-4-686-pae
- Complier: GCC (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2 (Code::Blocks)

I want to move a file from one location to another. Nothing complex like moving to different drives or to different file systems. I know the "standard" way to do this would be simply copying the file and then removing the original. But I want some way of preserving the file's ownership, mode, last access/modification, etc. . I am assuming that I will have to copy the file and then edit the new file's ownership, mode, etc. afterwards but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The usual way to move a file in C is to use [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), which sometimes fail.

If you cannot use the [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) syscall (e.g. because source and target are on different filesystems), you have to query the size, permission and other metadata of the source file with [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html); copy the data looping on [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (using a buffer of several kilobytes), [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) and the metadata using [chmod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html), [chown(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html), [utime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html). You might also care about copying attributes using [getxattr(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getxattr.2.html), [setxattr(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lsetxattr.2.html), [listxattr(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listxattr.2.html). You could also in some cases use [sendfile(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html), as commented by  [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin).

And if the source and target are on different filesystems, there is no way to make the move atomic and avoid race conditions (So using [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) is preferable when possible, because it is atomic according to its man page). The source file can always be modified (by another process) during the move operations...

So a practical way to move files is to first try doing a [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), and if that fails with `EXDEV` (when *oldpath* and *newpath* are not on the same mounted filesystem), then you need to copy bytes and metadata. Several libraries provide functions doing that, e.g. Qt [QFile::rename](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#rename).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) - and see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) - for more (and also try to [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) some [`mv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) command to understand what it is doing). That book is freely and legally downloadable (so you could find several copies on the Web).

The `/bin/mv` command (see [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html)) is part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) which is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You could either study its source code, or use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what that command does (in terms of [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)). In some [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) [Unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) like [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/), `mv` might be a shell builtin. See also [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

There are subtle corner cases (imagine another process or pthread doing some file operations on the same filesystem, directory, or files). Read some [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) for more.

Using a mix of [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html), [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) could be tricky if the file name contains weird characters such as <kbd>tab</kbd> or   or newlines, or starts with an initial `-`. See [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Comment: Thanks very much for the alternate option.

Comment: For Linux, [sendfile](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) provides a method for copy across filesystem boundaries that is more efficient than `read`, `write`. The original `sendfile` has size limits of `0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552)` bytes, but Linux also added the `sendfile64` wrapper with a wider type for the offset argument.

Comment: Advanced Linux Programming link seems to be broken.

Comment: Corrected. But you could find it too

Comment: Wow, that is a process... I think I'll stick to system("mv")

Answer (score 19):

If the original and new location for the file are on the same filesystem then a "move" is conceptually identical to a "[rename](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Renaming-Files.html)."

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rename (const char *oldname, const char *newname)
```

Comment: Dangerous.  Has race conditions - as do all file operations that rely on the name, not a file pointer.  You can check that it's the right file before calling renmae, but then there's some amount of time between the check and the actual rename operation.  In that time, it is possible that the original file could be replaced with a malicious file (and such vulns have existed in real applications).

Comment: Seeing as there doesn't seem to be a file rename function using a file pointer, it looks like you'll be forced to stat(), rename, then stat() again, to confirm that the file hasn't really changed - the new file is still teh same as the old file - before you ever use it

Comment: @atk: Why do you believe that `rename(2)` is dangerous? I believe it is atomic, since it is a syscall and its `man` page mentions atomicity!

Comment: You might want to tell the OP how to detect if both files are in the same filesystem and if not how to implement a copy function and then to `unlink()` the original.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - rename is atomic at the file system level. It is either oldname or newname, instantly. What  atk is saying that if you have code that finds a file by name (char*) and then renames it (with char*), that you are not 100% sure that the file you find the first time is the same file you are renaming, if another process is changing files on you.

Comment: Mark Lakata hit the nail on the head :)

Comment: But this is not a problem of rename ? Just a problem of files and rights. Right ?