# Renaming & moving my file based on the size is not always working in c. Why?

Tags: c, mv

I have an application, written in C, which generates various data parameters that I am logging into a text file named debug_log.txt. Whenever this log file reaches 1 MB, I am renaming the filename with timestamp ex debug_log_20200106_133000.txt & moving it in same directory. I am then reopening debug_log.txt to log new parameters.

```
if(stat("/home/log/debug_log.txt", &statFiledbg) == 0) 
{
    if(statFiledbg.st_size >= 1048576) // 1MB
    { 
        current_time = time(0);
        strftime(time_buffer, sizeof(time_buffer), "%Y%m%d_%H-%M-%S", gmtime(&current_time));
        sprintf(strSysCmddbg, "mv /home/log/debug_log.txt /home/log/debug_log%s.txt", time_buffer);
        system(strSysCmddbg);
        fp_dbglog = freopen("/home/log/debug_log.txt", "w", fp_dbglog);
    }
}
```

The code works most of the time until it doesn't. After running the application for couple days, I see that debug_log.txt grows beyond 1 MB while the last moved & renamed log file is empty.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Don't use `system("mv...` but use the proper [rename](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) function and check for errors.

Comment: Why are you using `system()` to run a `mv` command instead of just using [`rename()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) directly?

Comment: In other parts of my code, I am using system() commands as well. One of my senior developer in the company told me so. Is there anything wrong with using system()?

Comment: I wonder how the system reacts to a file moving when it has a FILE pointer open on it... Do you flush data your writting? You may want to `fclose` the file before moving it

Comment: _"One of my senior developer told me..."_: you should ask him why and show him this question and answers

Comment: @Mathieu, on a typical unix-like os using a native fs, it is perfectly fine to move/rename/delete a file that is still open

Comment: `system` is a really crappy function. If you really have to execute an external command, it is typically better to call `fork`/`exec`/`wait`

Comment: @HAL9000, [system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) does all those (internally) you mentioned in comment, why do you think its crappy?

Comment: You should probably flush and close `fp_dbglog` before performing any renaming of the file.  Most file systems use a write-behind cache so it might be worth checking that the file no longer exists (e.g. `stat`) before creating the new file, to verify any assumption that the file move is completed by the operating system.  Also I presume this section is atomic, i.e. the log isn't being written by another thread or process?

Comment: @IrAM, because when building a command string from arguments which is going to be split into arguments anyhow,  you have to be careful to escape all special characters, which you sooner or later are gonna screw up. The school that little Little Bobby Tables attends can tell you what happens then. Then you have the added bloat of launching the shell to do the parsing, no way to capture io, and probably a few others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rename` function from the C standard library (in `stdio.h`) and check `errno` if it failed to know the exact reason why it is failing.

When working with files, and I/O in general, there are many, many things that can go wrong.

> One of my senior developer in the company told me so. Is there anything wrong with using `system()`?

Yes: it is unnecessary (C and POSIX provide you with a function for basic usages like this), nonportable (it assumes you are in a system that has a "`mv`"), slower (it needs to spawn another process) and wrong for many use cases (eg. here there is no way to know what exactly failed unless you save the textual output of `mv`).

See questions and answers like [Moving a file on Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17440097/9305398) for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it a good idea to always use rename() instead of mv command?

Comment: It is the other way around: using `mv` is always a bad idea. Whether `rename()` is enough for you (it has limitations) or you need a more powerful function, it depends on your use case. In general, calling `system()` is usually a bad idea.